# For a UDT htfD with a UDT field htfD.rsData assigning result of request.security to this field does not work

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

for a UDT object `htfD1` with UDT field `rsD` why does assigning to `htfD1.rsD` fail while assigning to `rsD` work fine in the following script?
(Please run on BTCUSDT.P Bybit 1M chart, see the data window):

This works fine:

```
//@version=5
indicator("HTF bar_index",  overlay = true)

type rsData
    int             htfBi

type htfData
    rsData  rsD

rsF1(rsData _rsD) =>
    _rsD.htfBi := bar_index
    _rsD

var rsD1 = rsData.new()
var htfD1 = htfData.new(rsD1)

// Works fine when assigning to rsD1
rsD1 := request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "3M", (timeframe.period == "3M") ? rsF1(htfD1.rsD) : na, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
htfD1.rsD := na(rsD1) ? rsData.new(): rsD1

plotchar(na(rsD1) ? na : rsD1.htfBi, "rsD1.htfBi","", location.belowbar)
plotchar(na(htfD1.rsD) ? na : htfD1.rsD.htfBi, "htfD1.rsD.htfBi","", location.belowbar)
```

while this does not:

```
//@version=5
indicator("HTF bar_index",  overlay = true)

type rsData
    int             htfBi

type htfData
    rsData  rsD

rsF1(rsData _rsD) =>
    _rsD.htfBi := bar_index
    _rsD

var rsD1 = rsData.new()
var htfD1 = htfData.new(rsD1)

// once rsD1 is changed to htfD1.rsD everything fails
htfD1.rsD := request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "3M", (timeframe.period == "3M") ? rsF1(htfD1.rsD) : na, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
htfD1.rsD := na(htfD1.rsD) ? rsData.new(): rsD1

// adding or removing the following line does not help
// htfD1.rsD := rsD1

plotchar(na(rsD1) ? na : rsD1.htfBi, "rsD1.htfBi","", location.belowbar)
plotchar(na(htfD1.rsD) ? na : htfD1.rsD.htfBi, "htfD1.rsD.htfBi","", location.belowbar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like removing the strange condition `(timeframe.period == "3M")` inside the `request.security()` fixes the problem.
Such a condition may be helpful when trying to fill arrays from within request.security (since some parts of code within the functions called from within the request.security() are executed in chart's timeframe, if the return does not depend on those parts)

Still a strange behaviour...